# VB.Net VBDateTimePicker (nullableDateTimePicker)

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, datetimepicker

### Background

We have a legacy forms based VB.NET application that is currently being redeveloped into an c# MVC web based application. I need to keep the forms based application going whilst this redevelopment happens. Throughout the application (hundreds of fields), we have used a control called nullableDateTimePicker ([VBDateTimePicker.ProjectMentor.Windows.Controls.nullableDateTimePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5428/Nullable-DateTimePicker)) as we needed a control that could handle a NULL date.

### The problem

This control has worked fine for years, now however, it seems to have stopped working and when the control has a null value, choosing a date from the picker will not populate the picker. If the control has a date, the date will correctly change when selected from the picker. There must have been a windows update or some other environmental change that has kippered the control.

### The question

- In the NullableDateTimePicker.cs on the CodeProject source, we have the below:

  ```
  protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
  {
      base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
  }
  ```

  However, this does not appear to update the value when chosen **when the controls Value is set to null**. The Demo project that comes from codeproject (linked above and below) exhibits the same broken behaviour on a patched Windows 7 / Windows 8 machine.

For ease of download, I have also popped the zipped project [here on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c30msowak2wsla/NullableDateTimePicker_src.zip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid overriding the WndProc method and just override the OnCloseUp method instead:

```
//protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
//{
//  if (_isNull)
//  {
//    if (m.Msg == 0x4e)                         // WM_NOTIFY
//    {
//      NMHDR nm = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
//      if (nm.Code == -746 || nm.Code == -722)  // DTN_CLOSEUP || DTN_?
//        SetToDateTimeValue();
//    }
//  }
//  base.WndProc(ref m);
//}

protected override void OnCloseUp(EventArgs eventargs) {
  if (_isNull) {
    SetToDateTimeValue();
  }
  base.OnCloseUp(eventargs);
}
```